# Pass a comparator to java Collections.disjoint

Tags: java, collections

Is it possible to pass a comparator to Collections.disjoint? 
In the documentation I couldn't find a variation of the method to be accepting comparator, or am I missing something?

```
Collections.disjoint(c1, c2);
```

I can see in Collections documentation that sort (method of Collections) has two versions, one with comparator and one without:

```
sort(List<T> list)
sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

- Why disjoint doesn't have a version accepting comparator?
- What is an alternative way to pass a comparator if I can't modify the class of individual objects? (In my case the individual objects are of type String so I can't override the equals and hashcode.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer lies somewhere between a comment and a full-blown answer, but I believe the reason that `Collections.disjoint()` does not expose the possibility of using a custom comparator is that it doesn't *use* a comparator to compute the disjoint between two collections.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)):

> public static boolean disjoint(Collection c1,
>                  Collection c2)
>
> Returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.

The method which is used to determine if two elements are "in common" is the `equals()` method of each entry in the collection.  On the other hand, in Java a comparator is typically used to determine the relative *ordering* of two elements in a collection.

Comment: Unrelated: today I (hope to) get to legendary gold ... just saying thanks to all the folks I learned so much from ...

Comment: @GhostCat You may have set a record for earning Legendary with the lowest total rep.  If not, then very close to that record.

Comment: Yep. And when I started hunting I assumed to come in around 300. Now I am #230.